# Vue.js re-rendering sorted array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a basic sorting UI to sort comments based on some values:

Part of `CommentsSection` template:

```
<div v-if="numComments" class="tabs d-flex">
       <span class="text-muted">Sort by:</span>
       <div class="tab" :class="{active: tab === 0}" @click="sortComments(0)">Rating</div>
       <div class="tab" :class="{active: tab === 1}" @click="sortComments(1)">Newest</div>
       <div class="tab" :class="{active: tab === 2}" @click="sortComments(2)">Oldest</div>
</div>

<ul v-if="numComments" class="comments-list">
       <li is="comment" @delete="numComments -= 1" v-for="comment in sortedComments" :data="comment"></li>
</ul>
```

`CommentsSection`:

```
export default {
    name: 'comments-section',
    components: {
        CommentForm,
        Comment
    },
    props: ['comments', 'submissionId'],
    data() {
        return {
            tab: 0,
            numComments: this.comments.length,
            sortedComments: this.comments.slice()
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.sortComments();
    },
    methods: {
        sortComments(type = 0) {
            this.tab = type;
            if (type === 0) {
                this.sortedComments.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating);
            } else if (type === 1) {
                this.sortedComments.sort((a, b) => moment(b.create_time).unix() - moment(a.create_time).unix());
            } else {
                this.sortedComments.sort((a, b) => moment(a.create_time).unix() - moment(b.create_time).unix());
            }
        },
      ...
    }
  ...
}
```

`CommentSingle` (component being rendered in list):

```
export default {
    name: 'comment-single',
    props: ['data'],
    data() {
        return {
            agree: this.data.rated === 1,
            disagree: this.data.rated === -1
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

The `CommentSingle` template is not being re-rendered so `agree` and `disagree` don't update. But the actual list does render the proper sort when clicking each sorting tab, but each comment in the list has the wrong `agree` and `disagree` (the original sorted array's values). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: possible to create a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by binding a `key` to the rendered component:

```
<li is="comment" @delete="numComments -= 1" v-for="comment in sortedComments" :key="comment.id" :data="comment"></li>
```

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key